# Blackberry memory limit for a screen?

Tags: blackberry, memory-leaks, bitmap

I wonder if there is some memory limit for the Mainscreen in BlackBerry? I mean I have like *Garage Screen* in my game and 60 cars + other images initiating and it seems loading time causes errors on real device, Bold 9700. Is it possible that the images cause memory errors? Total size of those images is about 2mb in /res folder.

Comment: Nope, no exceptions, seems it is the device issue.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.  One work around you can try is do not load all the images in to memory at a time, instead, you can load the images as needed.  This will be memory efficient.

Thanks

Naveen M